# Does "display:none" prevent content being loaded?

Tags: css, video, mobile, roaming, mobile-data

I want to hide a video on mobile devices.
I did this by using "@media screen and (max-width: ###px)" and "display:none", this works fine but does that prevent the video from being loaded?

Basically I want the video to be not loaded with mobile data roaming, so that users on mobile devices won't use their roaming data for that.

Is there a more convenient way of doing this?

Comment: Videos don't autoplay unless you force them to, and they're only loaded when you start playing them in most modern browsers.

Comment: So how do I prevent a video from being loaded on mobile devices, if it is on autoplay?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the css `display: none` then the answer is the video will still be loaded over the mobile network but it would not be visible to the end user. That being said a user could theoretically change the CSS for that element so it would display and then they could watch the video.

Answer (score 0):

Video will be loaded but it is not visible to user. To pervent loading video, instead of changing css, you can remove the video from HTML using JS

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: This webpage should be able to help you https://catalin.red/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/